# My IIS does not recognize my WCF custom binding

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

Today, I have a problem with hosting my custom service host using [custom binding](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/duplexhttp). I have tried to implement ServiceHostFactory but when i right click to view with in browser, the error appeared as IIS does not recognize my custom binding (duplexHttpBinding).

My web.config is here:

```
<services>
        <service name="TestWcf.Service1"
            behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/Service1"/>
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
            <endpoint
                address="http://localhost:9999/Service1"
                binding="duplexHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="binding1"
                contract="TestWcf.IService" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
        <duplexHttpBinding>
            <binding name="binding1"
                     closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                     openTimeout="00:01:00"
                     receiveTimeout="24.20:31:23.6470000"
                     sendTimeout="02:01:00"
                     session="ReliableSession"
                     sessionTimeout="00:10:00"
                     maxUndeliveredMessages="100"
                     maxMessagesInBatch="10"
                     maxPollingReplyInterval="00:02:00">
            </binding>
        </duplexHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

and code in dervied class is here:

```
public class CustomServiceHost : ServiceHostFactory
{
    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string service, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        DuplexHttpBinding binding = new DuplexHttpBinding();
        binding.Name = "binding1";

        Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/Service1");
        Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:9999/Service1");


        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), baseAddresses);
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, address);

        return serviceHost;
    }
}
```

and in SVC file

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="TestWcf.Service1" Factory="TestWcf.CustomServiceHost" %>
```

Do I miss something in the context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must register new binding as [binding extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa749847.aspx) in your configuration file.

Comment: Thanks a lot: After I did, I still found an error "No protocol binding matches the given address "http://localhost:9999/Service1". Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration." Any suggestion on that?

Comment: You are using Https. In such case your custom binding has to use httpsTransport channel. Is there any security element in the binding's configuration? If yes you must configure it to transport mode.